# How to anchor tag to a specific div from a dropdown menu

Tags: javascript, html, drop-down-menu, anchor

I have a page where I am using a dropdown selector, and am looking to anchor link the sections in my URL, but when I use *#show1* at the end of my URL, the specified dropdown does not show.

Any insight as to what I am doing incorrectly?

Thank you in advance!

**Snippet of current HTML:**

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>      

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#myselection').on('change', function(){
        var demovalue = $(this).val(); 
        $("div.myDiv").hide();
        $("#show"+demovalue).show();
    });
});
</script> 
<style>
.myDiv{
    display:none;
    padding:10px;
    margin-top:20px;
}  
#showOne{
    border:1px solid red;
}
#showTwo{
    border:1px solid green;
}
#showThree{
    border:1px solid blue;
}
</style> 

<select id="myselection">
    <option>Select Option</option>
    <option value="One">One</option>
    <option value="Two">Two</option>
    <option value="Three">Three</option>
</select>
<div id="showOne" class="myDiv">
    You have selected option <strong>"One"</strong>.
</div>
<div id="showTwo" class="myDiv">
    You have selected option <strong>"Two"</strong>.
</div>
<div id="showThree" class="myDiv">
    You have selected option <strong>"Three"</strong>.
</div>
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. You want to have anchor in the link (like `index.html#show1` and with that anchor you want an option to be selected in dropdown? Or you want the page to skip to that section?

Comment: @MikeSzyndel - thank you for your response. Yes, I would like that anchor to have specified option to open in the download (if that specific anchor is used in the URL). 

ie - if the url has https://www.pagename.com#section1 I want the page to automatically open the 'section1' specified dropdown.

Comment: I'm still not sure I understand. Can you give us an interactive example? Got it started for you

Comment: @MikeSzyndel i have added in an interactive code above. I am trying to achieve the below functionality: there to be an anchor associated with say "option one" so when they type in the URL with the #anchor specification, the page will automatically open that dropdown tab, instead on being directed to the page where they have to navigate the dropdown & click "option one"

Comment: I may not be able to answer your question, just wanted to help make it more answerable. Does the answer below help?

Answer (score 0):

I updated your code as below; added some `<a />` tag to change the dropdown selected value and change URL in the browser without reloading the page. Also I added some `<br />` tag to test that page will not scroll down.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script>
      $(document).ready(function () {

        //In the Html create links, when user clicks will change url and dropdown without scroll to div
        $("a.hashLink").on("click", function (e) {
          e.preventDefault();

          //get dropdown item value from href attribute
          var sItem = $(this).attr("href").replace("#show", ""); 
          $("#myselection").val(sItem).trigger("change"); //change dropdown to new value

          //In modern browsers and HTML5, there is a method called pushState on window history. 
          //That will change the URL and push it to the history without loading the page.
          window.history.pushState(
            { page: "#show" + sItem },
            sItem,
            "#show" + sItem
          );
        });

        // check URL hash value on page load
        var hash = window.location.hash.substr(1); // remove the '#' character
        if (hash) {
          // trigger change event of the dropdown based on hash value
          $("#myselection").val(hash.replace("show", "")).trigger("change");
        }

        $("#myselection").on("change", function () {
          var demovalue = $(this).val();
          $("div.myDiv").hide();
          $("#show" + demovalue).show();
        });
      });
    </script>
    <style>
      .myDiv {
        display: none;
        padding: 10px;
        margin-top: 20px;
      }
      #showOne {
        border: 1px solid red;
      }
      #showTwo {
        border: 1px solid green;
      }
      #showThree {
        border: 1px solid blue;
      }
    </style>

    <div>
      <p><a class="hashLink" href="#showOne">got to one</a></p>
      <p><a class="hashLink" href="#showTwo">got to two</a></p>
      <p><a class="hashLink" href="#showThree">got to three</a></p>
    </div>

    <select id="myselection">
      <option>Select Option</option>
      <option value="One">One</option>
      <option value="Two">Two</option>
      <option value="Three">Three</option>
    </select>
    <br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
    <div id="showOne" class="myDiv">
      You have selected option <strong>"One"</strong>.
    </div>
    <br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
    <div id="showTwo" class="myDiv">
      You have selected option <strong>"Two"</strong>.
    </div>
    <br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
    <div id="showThree" class="myDiv">
      You have selected option <strong>"Three"</strong>.
    </div>
```